# Query to return latest entry by last three users

Tags: mysql

I have a query that successfully populates the "Recent Reports" box at http://budburst.org with the last three submitted observations.

Currently, if a single person submits more than one observation, they appear multiple times on the list.  What I'd like to do is tweak the query so that only the *latest* observation for the last three *users* is selected.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT tbl_observations.ID,tbl_observations.Observer_ID, 
       tbl_observations.Station_ID, tbl_observations.Species_ID,
       tbl_observations.Species_ID_Fix,tbl_observations.Phenophase_ID,
       tbl_observations.Observation_Date, tbl_observations.Creation_Date,
       tbl_species.Common_Name, tbl_people.First_Name, tbl_people.Last_Name,
       tbl_people.Addr_City, tbl_people.Addr_State, tbl_stations.Station_City,
       tbl_stations.Station_State, tbl_phenophases.Phenophase_Name, 
       tbl_users.UserName
FROM tbl_observations
JOIN tbl_species ON tbl_observations.Species_ID = tbl_species.Species_ID
JOIN tbl_stations ON tbl_observations.Station_ID = tbl_stations.Station_ID
JOIN tbl_people ON tbl_observations.Observer_ID = tbl_people.Person_ID
JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_users.User_ID = tbl_people.Person_ID
JOIN tbl_phenophases ON tbl_observations.Phenophase_ID = tbl_phenophases.Phenophase_ID
WHERE (YEAR(tbl_observations.Observation_Date) = YEAR(CURDATE()))
AND (tbl_species.Common_Name <> '--Other--')
AND (tbl_users.UserName NOT LIKE 'pbbtest%')
ORDER BY tbl_observations.Creation_Date DESC, tbl_observations.ID DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: Did you ever get the query to work? I have a query that comes close, but returns more than 3 in certain cases.

Comment: I haven't made much progress.  every time I think I have this figured out, it turns out that it's skipping "valid" observations on the same date!  I've tried various queries based on max(), but regardless of what I do, I get one obs per day (but at least the users don't repeat).  Quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

here is an untested idea:  just select the MAX observation and group by the observer.

```
SELECT o.m_ID,tbl_observations.Observer_ID, 
       tbl_observations.Station_ID, tbl_observations.Species_ID,
       tbl_observations.Species_ID_Fix,tbl_observations.Phenophase_ID,
       tbl_observations.Observation_Date, tbl_observations.Creation_Date,
       tbl_species.Common_Name, tbl_people.First_Name, tbl_people.Last_Name,
       tbl_people.Addr_City, tbl_people.Addr_State, tbl_stations.Station_City,
       tbl_stations.Station_State, tbl_phenophases.Phenophase_Name, 
       tbl_users.UserName
FROM tbl_observations
, (select max( id ) m_id, observer_id from tbl_observations group by observer_id ) o
JOIN tbl_species ON tbl_observations.Species_ID = tbl_species.Species_ID
JOIN tbl_stations ON tbl_observations.Station_ID = tbl_stations.Station_ID
JOIN tbl_people ON tbl_observations.Observer_ID = tbl_people.Person_ID
JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_users.User_ID = tbl_people.Person_ID
JOIN tbl_phenophases ON tbl_observations.Phenophase_ID = tbl_phenophases.Phenophase_ID
WHERE tbl_observations.observer_id = o.observer_id
AND tbl_observations.id = o.id
AND (YEAR(tbl_observations.Observation_Date) = YEAR(CURDATE()))
AND (tbl_species.Common_Name <> '--Other--')
AND (tbl_users.UserName NOT LIKE 'pbbtest%')
ORDER BY tbl_observations.Creation_Date DESC, tbl_observations.ID DESC LIMIT 0,3
```